# Is a Roman Catholic obligated to believe in the Trinity?

Tags: catholicism, trinity, doubt

There are many people who are technicially born into Christian homes, yet they don't fully agree with the doctrine of Trinity etc.

According to the creed of Roman Catholic Christianity, if someone is not 100% comfortable with the concept of Trinity (that is, believing it without a doubt in their mind), does that automatically make them 1) a Non-Christian and consequently 2) go to Hell

Comment: @Blankman Welcome to C.SE! When you get the chance, please check out our [about] and specifically [How we are different than other sites](http://tinyurl.com/csedifferent). What's going on is that we are looking for a perspective - thanks for understanding.

Answer (score 10):

Trinity is a Dogma of the Catholic Church. Hence as with all dogmas a Catholic is bound to believe it in order to maintain the bond of faith.

You have asked: **if *someone* is not 100% comfortable.....** Who is this someone? If they are non-baptised person, Catholic church has no official stand regarding them, only God will know.

If they are baptized Catholic then:

- Once a Catholic always a Catholic. Even a excommunicated person is a Christian who is not in union with the body of Christ. Baptism leaves a indelible mark on your soul.<sup>CCC 1272</sup>
- No-one can be sure about any specific individual will or will not go to hell. That is, only God can tell whether they will be saved or not. But if they are willfully refusing to believe a dogma, *a divinely revealed truth, proclaimed as such by the infallible teaching authority of the Church*, then it can be implied that they are refusing to remain in the church. And those who refuse to remain in the Church will not be saved.<sup>CCC 846</sup>

One *being not comfortable* is different from one *says he believes Jesus is not God*. Your question title and its content differ in its meaning.

If one is not comfortable:

Please remember you don't have to understand a dogma to believe it. So, you can believe in a dogma even if you have doubt. All that is required is your full will, *For as long as one remains willing to submit to the Church's decision he remains a Catholic Christian at heart and his wrong beliefs are only transient errors and fleeting opinions*<sup>[CE : Heresy](http://www.newadvent.org/cathen/07256b.htm)</sup>.

If one ***says*** he does not believe in a dogma, and they fully understand the way they are in disagreement with the Catholic Church:

This will make him a Heretic. A person who obstinately persists in heresy will not be in union with the church and hence cannot be saved.

Comment: One thing that I can't understand, is how can you believe in something yet have a doubt?  Meaning if I ask this person if you belief in the Trinity, they say "I am baptized and raised in a Catholic family", but I can't answer the question because I have my doubts and I am not sure.  Is this person (in theory) still a Catholic?

Comment: @Blankman, as I answered in my quested, once baptized he is always a catholic. Everybody has doubts, its natural. Some great saints had doubts all thru their life. It not the doubt but how one reacts to it matters. These doubts are considered _transient errors and fleeting opinions_ as long as you try to clear them up and not give in and accept them as facts.

Comment: @Blankman, belief is choosing to agree or go along with with something. Doubt is based on a lack of knowledge, not a lack of belief. You can continue to believe as you work through your doubts, because ultimately belief is a choice. If your belief is true – that is, if you choose to go along with and agree with Christ – then Christ will transform that belief into a motivating faith and teach you through the Spirit what you need to know so that your doubt becomes knowledge.